# How to handle error records in batch apex when trying to insert or update data to other object

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

I worked on batch apex which will insert or update contact object from SIS_Staging__c object.

can anyone guide me how to handle error records here, from SIS_Staging__c object I am inserting or updating contact, if any record is failed then I want to update text field on SIS_Staging__c object with error message.

My apex class is below:

```
global class BatchSISstagingObject implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,  Database.stateful{
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Name, First_Name__c,Last_Name__c,Email__c,Mailing_Country__c,SIS_Application_Id__c,AdmTyp__c,Resident_Tuition__c,ActnRsn__c,Admit_Term__c,Home_Country__c,Plan__c,Prog1__c,Prog__c,
                                      ProgActn__c
                                     FROM SIS_Staging__c WHERE Status__c = 'New'
                                    ]);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC , List <SIS_Staging__c> staginglist) {
    Set<String> uniquekeySet = new Set<String>();
    for(SIS_Staging__c stagingObj : staginglist){
        uniquekeySet.add(stagingObj.Name);
    }
    List<Contact> contactToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    List<Contact> contactToInsert = new List<Contact>();
    Map<String,Contact> studentIdTOContact = new Map<String,Contact>();
    List<Contact> conList2 = [SELECT ID,SIS_Student_ID__c,FirstName,LastName FROM CONTACT WHERE SIS_Student_ID__c IN:uniquekeySet];
    for(Contact conObj : conList2){
        studentIdTOContact.put(conObj.SIS_Student_ID__c,conObj);    
    }
    for (SIS_Staging__c acct : staginglist){ 
          if(studentIdTOContact.containsKey(acct.Name)){
             Contact con = studentIdTOContact.get(acct.Name);
             con.FirstName = acct.First_Name__c;
             con.LastName = acct.Last_Name__c;
             con.hed__AlternateEmail__c = acct.Email__c;
             con.SIS_Student_ID__c = acct.Name;
             con.hed__Country_of_Origin__c = acct.Home_Country__c;
             con.Current_Country_of_Study__c = acct.Mailing_Country__c;
             contactToUpdate.add(con);

          }else{
              Contact con = new Contact();
             con.FirstName = acct.First_Name__c;
             con.LastName = acct.Last_Name__c;
             con.hed__AlternateEmail__c = acct.Email__c;
             con.SIS_Student_ID__c = acct.Name;
             con.hed__Country_of_Origin__c = acct.Home_Country__c;
             con.Current_Country_of_Study__c = acct.Mailing_Country__c;
             contactToInsert.add(con);

          }
    }


    if(!contactToInsert.isEmpty()){
        insert contactToInsert;
    }
    if(!contactToUpdate.isEmpty()){

        Update contactToUpdate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Databse.SaveResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm) for individually checking success/failure of each record update or insert.

```
if(!contactToUpdate.isEmpty()){ 
        Database.SaveResult[] updateResults = Database.update(contactToUpdate, false);

        List<SIS_Staging__c> errsStaging = new List<SIS_Staging__c>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<updateResults.size();i++){
            if (updateResults.get(i).isSuccess()){
                updateResults.get(i).getId();                    
            } else if (!updateResults.get(i).isSuccess()){
                errsStaging.add(new SIS_Staging__c(
                    Contact__c=contactToUpdate.get(i).Id, 
                    Error_Message__c=updateResults.get(i).getErrors().get(0).getMessage()
                ));
            }                
        }
        if(errsStaging.size()>0) insert errsCons;
    }
    if(!contactToInsert.isEmpty()){
        Database.SaveResult[] insertResults = Database.insert(contactToInsert, false);

        List<SIS_Staging__c> errsStaging = new List<SIS_Staging__c>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<insertResults.size();i++){
            if (insertResults.get(i).isSuccess()){ } 
            else if (!insertResults.get(i).isSuccess()){ // there is no contact as its not created
                errsStaging.add(new SIS_Staging__c(
                    Error_Message__c=insertResults.get(i).getErrors().get(0).getMessage()
                ));
            }                
        }
        if(errsStaging.size()>0) insert errsCons;
    }
```

**However, note that in either updateResults or insertResults, you need to add more information in SIS_Staging__c like stack trace, fields etc apart from error message. You need multiple fields for logging all this info.**

Comment: is it possible to update the error message on SIS_Staging__c record, I have Error__c field on SIS_Staging__c object, if any error occurs then I need to update that field with error message

Comment: modified answer for creating `SIS_Staging__c`

Comment: your answer make sense for me but the thing is I don't have any relationship between Contact and SIS_Staging__c object, on both objects I have only SIS_Student_ID__c field which is same, basing on this field I am updating or inserting contact from SIS_Staging__c, is it possible for error message also to update SIS_Staging__c based on this SIS_Student_ID__c field

Comment: Yes, you can take this answer as reference and add logic in respective insert/update and success/failure blocks as required. If you have a different question, then I would suggest to open different question and close this question by clicking on tick.

Answer (score 0):

Use Database.insert which is partial insert the collection of data, please read [Database.insert() Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_saveresult.htm#apex_methods_system_database_saveresult)

```
List<Database.SaveResult> saveResultList = Database.insert(insertList, false);

// Iterate through saveResultList based on isSuccess capture the failed records
for (Database.SaveResult sr : saveResultList) {
    if (!sr.isSuccess()) {
        // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
        System.debug('Successfully inserted ' + sr.getId());
    }
    else {
        // Operation failed, so get all errors                
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            //store this info in new collection 
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('feild Error ' + err.getFields());
        }
    }
}
```

For Update Case use `Database.update(updateList,false)` other will same

```
List<Database.SaveResult> saveResultList = Database.update(updateList, false);

    // Iterate through saveResultList based on isSuccess capture the failed records
    for (Database.SaveResult sr : saveResultList) {
        if (!sr.isSuccess()) {
            // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
            System.debug('Successfully inserted ' + sr.getId());
        }
        else {
            // Operation failed, so get all errors                
            for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                //store this info in new collection 
                System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                System.debug('feild Error ' + err.getFields());
            }
        }
    }
```